# Как пользоваться WSARecv?

Tags: windows, сокет, c++, linux

Кто может объяснить, как пользоваться WSARecv? Я вижу, что туда нужно передать заранее подготовленный буфер для чтения и меня это каждый раз напрягает. Есть вариант, при котором я смогу лишь получать размер пришедших данных? А читать буду сам.

Периодически ищу более простые способы работы с соккетами. Но к сожалению упорно остаюсь на стандартном варианте из `POSIX: socket(), listen(), select()`...

Есть простые и шустрые варианты работы с соккетами под линукс и винду? Состоящие из получения сообщения о данных в соккете и возможности в него писать. Думаю почитать про работу с соккетами через сигналы на линуксе. И как вариант переписать TCP стек, к сожалению этот код будет требовать права администратора.

Comment: Не понятно.

     А читать буду сам.

Откуда Вы будете сами читать? С листочка в соответствии с rfc1149? Или откуда?

     И как вариант переписать TCP стек

И перепаять схему сетевого адаптера?
PS: вариант "читать сам" и "переписать TCP стек" вполне возможен при создании устройств на микроконтроллерах...

Comment: @mikelsv, Вы для начала определите свою истинную ориентацию (WSARecv или linux).

Вообще с сигналами связываться не советую. Если надо что-то гибкое посмотрите на fcntl/ioctl для неблокирующего IO вместе c poll() или epoll() (но это чисто линукс).

А может одного poll()(epoll()) будет достаточно.

--

Переписывать TCP стек будете сразу по завершению tftp? (кстати, как он движется? не остыли?)

Comment: Я как-то писал стек на UDP и оно даже работало. В tcp должно быть не особо сложнее. Но эта затея скорее для развлечения.

У меня ориентация сразу на винду и на линукс.

Сейчас пытаюсь приделать сервер tftp на андроид. Пока упирается. А, нет, все наконец-то заработало. "Received 2625504 bytes in 17.8 seconds" через wifi.

Comment: @mikelsv, а прием файла в сервере уже сделали?

Comment: @avp, прием давно уже сделал. Сейчас готова вся компания: клиент и сервер, под линукс и винду, и сервер под андроид. Тестировалось с tftp клиентом на линуксе. Не подскажете tftp сервер, хочу убедиться, что мой клиент работает как надо. Из оставшегося, мои программы не поддерживают расширения протокола и режим ascii.

Comment: @mikelsv, не занимался tftp, так что не подскажу. Сам (когда Ваш первый вариант запускал) клиента методом тыка выбирал (он у меня стандартно отсутствовал).

А API (для Си !!!) и свои расширения (например чтение содержимого директории у сервера) не планируете?

И киньте url, может возьму новую версию, потестирую в линуксе (правда быстро не обещаю).

Comment: @avp, качать отсюда svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource, доступ должен быть открыт для всех. Потребуется /msvlib и клиент /msv-tftp или сервер /msv-tftpd. В /msv-tftpd/doc/tftp_ru.txt мое описание протокола и работы программы.

Код на с++, не вижу, как здесь сделать API для Си. И честно говоря не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Буду рад услышать ваши мысли.

Честно говоря, я вижу tftp только как некий проект для прокладывания пути. Проще написать новый проект на TCP, который будет уметь получать список файлов и остальное. Или взять тот же FTP.

Comment: А просто какого-нибудь tar-овского файлика нет? Потом make, и вперед...

Вы пишете:

    Потребуется /msvlib и клиент /msv-tftp или сервер /msv-tftpd.

зачем они? Ведь у Вас же реализованы и клиент (надеюсь командная строка?) и сервер. Вот их взаимодействие и интересно. 

Конечно, это не отменяет тестирование со стандартными tftp и tftpd (хотя, лично мне устанавливать и настраивать его неохота).

--

Про API. Раз не видите, как сделать API для Си, значит его не будет. Я имел в виду удобный набор функций (какой решать Вам, как разработчику) для перекачки файлов на/с Ваш tftpd.

Comment: @avp, починил svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource , теперь качается.

Я бы сказал, что функции на си для работы с tftp стоит писать, когда в них есть потребность. Как только у меня появится устройство поддерживающее только си, сразу напишу. А до этого мне негде использовать этот код. Не вижу его практической ценности. Если посмотреть, главный цикл в tftp клиенте, в котором происходит вся работа практически написан в стиле си. Если его отделить получится функция загрузки/скачивания файла.

Answer (score 2):

> > Кто может объяснить, как пользоваться WSARecv? Я вижу, что туда нужно передать заранее подготовленный буфер для чтения

Можно выделить один раз буфер и использовать повторно. Обычно так и делают.

> > Есть вариант при котором я смогу лишь получать размер пришедших данных? А читать буду сам.

Плохой способ. Мало того, что нужно будет два запроса вместо одного, так ещё есть другая проблема. Между тем, как запросили размер и пошли его читать, могут прибежать новые данные. А WSARecv (как и recv) читает сколько может и кол-во возвращает.

> > Есть простые и шустрые варианты работы с соккетами под линукс и винду? Состоящие из получения сообщения о данных в соккете и возможности в него писать.

Да, например epoll для линукса и [I/O Completion Ports (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx). В BSD часто  используют [kqueue](http://www.insight-it.ru/tag/kqueue/). Но обычно используют готовые библиотеки, например [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/). Ну и конечно boost::asio и [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html).

> > И как вариант переписать TCP стек, к сожалению этот код будет требовать права администратора.

TCP стек - не такая простая задача. Вы думаете, что сможете написать лучше?

Ещё почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ideco/blog/146340/).

**update:**
Узнать, сколько байтов можно прочитать прям сейчас с сокета все же можно. Для этого используется такой вызов

```
ioctlsocket(socket, FIONREAD, &toRead)
```

А вот по поводу деталей - отсылаю к соответствующему [руководству](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Хмм. Почитал статьи. Вопрос смещается в сторону обеспечения 10к соединений. По итогам подумываю использовать WSARecv и посмотреть, что из этого выйдет.

Про TCP: Достаточно написать TCP стек не хуже. Но работать он будет намного лучше, в силу доступности кучи информации. Но вероятно медленней. Это пожалуй можно сделать темой исследования.

Comment: В каком из ядер будете TCP менять?

Comment: @avp, зачем в ядрах? Каждой программе свой TCP стек!

Comment: И свой ethernet. Или хотя бы wi-fi модуль.

Реализуйте rfc1149 (и наследников) на андроиде (только не забывайте о технике безопасности, чтобы носители пакетов корпус не запачкали).

Comment: а как же свой байт, на 10 с половиной бит?:)

Comment: @mikelsv, "каждой свой" - интересная мысль.

Идеями (с нетривиальными деталями) реализации не поделитесь?

Comment: @avp, идея реализации довольно проста: написать код, работающий с сырыми соккетами, реализующими TCP и через него посылать данные.

@KoVadim, буду знать, что так можно.

Comment: @mikelsv, наверное я плохо с ними (raw sockets) знаком. Мне казалось, что accept/connect с ними не проходят. Можно делать sendto и recv в режиме просмотра (Promiscuous mode).

Это не так?

Comment: @avp, нет, все так. accept() это лишь реакция на определенный пакет, с кодом начала соединения. Прелесть всей задачи в отбрасывании абстракции и работе с чистыми пакетами. И полная свобода, на мой взгляд. Например, можно не закрывать соединение, если нет связи. Не знаю, можно ли это настроить в обычных соккетах.

Comment: @mikelsv,  svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource не забирает.

(там комментарии кончились)


Попробовал взять Ваш tftp, делаю:

    svn co  svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource
    .....

Короче, хочет --username и --password

или Вы что-то другое имели в виду, предоставив этот url?